Is there a way to repeat an observable until other observable emits?
I'm trying to run an observable repeatedly until some other observable is emitted.
I don't want to stop currently unfinished observable, I only want it not to repeat again.
ts/rxjs
I tried using takeUntil, but this closes the stream$, without it actually finishing (it cuts it before 1000ms timer).
const stream$ = interval(1).pipe(takeUntil(timer(1000)));
stream$.pipe(repeat(), takeUntil(timer(1500)));

If we agree that stream$ runs for 1000ms before closing, what I expect to happen is that it should run 2 times 1000ms in this case. I need some sort of operator that would stop repeating the observable upon some event$.
Something like this:
const stream$ = interval(1).pipe(takeUntil(timer(1000)));
stream$.pipe(repeatUntil(timer(1500)));



We can use takeWhile and wait for the zeroth element emission and then trigger the take condition.
This will generate the output, where we seem to receive an emission even after the set threshold time.
const { rxObserver } = require('api/v0.3');
const { timer, interval, Subject  } = require('rxjs');
const { take, map, repeat, takeUntil, takeWhile, toArray} = require('rxjs/operators');

const msg = 'awesome';
let turnOff = true;

interval(33).pipe(
    takeUntil(timer(100)),
    repeat(),
    takeWhile((data) => data === 0 ? turnOff : true),
  ).subscribe(rxObserver());
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    turnOff = false;
  }, 134)

Try toggling the value of setTimeout between 134 and 133.
Marbles diagram for the below code - Try it on ThinkRx -> use the above code to see it in action on this website.

This doesn't really work in the way I want it to work. I need to repeat exactly the same stream$, from it's start to completion, and keep repeating it until some external event$ emits. interval(33).pipe(takeUntil(timer(100))).pipe(repeat()).subscribe(rxObserver());
This will repeat 012, 012, 012, 012... marbles. When I want to stop this at some point, I want it to complete currently repeating observable stream, so it ends up on marble 2 and not cut it on marble 0 or 1.

@DarkoMitic updated my answer!

That's an interesting approach, and it does what I want. In my case I would use timer(0, 33) instead of interval(33) that wouldn't delay zeroth emission, and it would also stack the last emission with the zeroth emission from the next loop. Before you gave me this solution, I used the combination of repeatWhen and takeUntil with a filter:
repeatWhen(() => trigger$.pipe(filter((repeat) => repeat))), takeUntil(trigger$.pipe(filter((repeat) => !repeat))), but your answer is much more elegant, and doesn't require trigger$ emission at the end of each loop.
Thank you very much!
